# get default printer name in web application published in hosting

Tags: asp.net, printing, printers

I have my web page published in hosting, and I cant print my reports because (I tink) my web application can`t get my printer name.

An Idea please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to print from the code-behind of your application?

Comment: yes, but the application takes the default printer of the hosting. Microsoft OneNote

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't be able to get your local printer. It could only grab a printer that is setup on the hosting server as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

use web config file to set your printer name. use this name in printer settings.

```
<add key="PrinterName" value="\\192.168.1.1\Canon LBP6000/LBP6018" />
```

in c#

```
 PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
 string printerName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrinterName"];
 printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
```

did work for me .